# Why does AttachDBFile make everything slower?

Tags: performance

In my ASP.NET app, I had tested a query against a 200.000 rows table with two connection strings, one connect to a remote SQL Server and once use `AttachDBFile` to attach to a database file in `App_Data`.

The query with the first connection is much faster than the later. Anybody could shed some light on this for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are comparing two different servers. Likely different hardware specs, possibly different versions. Possibly even querying different data. Apples and oranges. The attach is probably a red herring (there is a cost in attach and querying cold data, but will amortize over many queries. You *do* measure hot cached and repeated runs, [don't you](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2413037)?)

Read [How to analyse SQL Server performance](http://rusanu.com/2014/02/24/how-to-analyse-sql-server-performance/) to root-cause the performance problem.

Comment: Since my remote Server has the same versions, hardware specs and attached the same mdf/ldf, maybe "attach and querying cold data" is to blame.